# Baffling gcc complaint about usage of Qt4 setValidator

Tags: c++, gcc, qt4, compiler-errors

We're stumped as to why gcc complains about this line in our app:

```
doubleFrom->setValidator(new QDoubleValidator(doubleFrom));
```

with these complaints:

```
error: expected type-specifier before 'QDoubleValidator'
error: expected `)' before 'QDoubleValidator'
error: no matching function for call to 'QLineEdit::setValidator(int*)'
candidates are: void QLineEdit::setValidator(const QValidator*)
```

(I've chopped out long-winded paths to files, line numbers.)

Yes, setValidator wants to be fed a const QValidator*, and that's what we're doing in that one line of source.  Why does gcc want to see a ')' prematurely, and think we're feeding setValidator an int*?

Of course,  "this compiled fine yesterday, and we haven't changed anything. Really!"

Comment: Try to first create the object and assign to a temporary. Call setValidator with this variable. Then see which line fails to compile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is really basic and obvious, I know, but did you `#include <QDoubleValidator>`?
"Expected type-specifier before <identifier that should name a type>" almost always means that the type definition isn't visible.

Comment: That was it!   Odd, how either it compiled without that before, or that line vanished without any record of that change in our svn repo.  I had even tried svn revert with no luck.

Comment: It may have compiled because another header included it and you included that header

Comment: @David: Just what I was about to say.

Comment: @David - yeah, that's our hunch, with some unknown number of nested #includes, but we're not going to spend time verifying it.  This is a very large software system full of code surprises.

Comment: So, is there an "oh, duh" badge for asking questions with obvious answerss?

Comment: It's only obvious if you've seen that error message enough times to know what it really means.  A lot of GCC's error messages assume you know the C++ grammar the way a compiler author knows it :-(